# Cannot resolve "Object is of type 'unknown'" problem in Angular TypeScript component

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my Angular TypeScript application, I have a component containing a function designed to upload some test data (that I have in another .ts file in the same folder) to Angular Firestore. Within the function there is a for loop that establishes "customer" as a variable of type *unknown*. Inside the for loop, when I attempt to use this customer variable as both an argument in a sub-function, and as a console.log variable, the IDE does not like it. In both cases, I get an inline **"Object is of type 'unknown'"** error. I've scoured this site and Googled and cannot find a solution to this exact problem. Can someone shed some light?

Here is my component:

*about.component.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';

import { CUSTOMERS, findJobSitesForCustomer } from './db-data';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent {

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }

  async uploadData() {
    const customersCollection = this.db.collection('customers');
    const customers = await this.db.collection('customers').get();
    for (let customer of Object.values(CUSTOMERS)) {
      const newCustomer = this.removeId(customer);
      const customerRef = await customersCollection.add(newCustomer);
      const jobSites = await customerRef.collection('jobSites');
      const customerJobSites = findJobSitesForCustomer(customer['id']);
      // IDE does not like above usage of 'customer' - I get 'Object is of type 'unknown'' inline error
      console.log(`Uploading customer ${customer['description']}`);
      // IDE does not like above usage of 'customer' - I get 'Object is of type 'unknown'' inline error
      for (const jobSite of customerJobSites) {
        const newJobSite = this.removeId(jobSite);
        delete newJobSite.customerId;
        await jobSites.add(newJobSite);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the aforementioned test data file:

db-data.ts

```
export const CUSTOMERS: any = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Lowe`s',
    seqNo: 1,
    address1: '200-B Mill Road',
    address2: '',
    address3: '',
    city: 'Oaks',
    state: 'PA',
    zipCode: '19456',
    phone: '6106501920',
    emailAddress: 'info@lowes.com',
    websiteUrl: 'http://www.lowes.com',
    billingMethod: 'Fixed'
  },

  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Valley Veterinary Hospital',
    seqNo: 1,
    address1: '1145 Valley Forge Road',
    address2: '',
    address3: '',
    city: 'Phoenixville',
    state: 'PA',
    zipCode: '19460',
    phone: '6109358110',
    emailAddress: 'custservice@valleyveterinaryhospital.net',
    websiteUrl: 'http://www.valleyveterinaryhospital.net',
    billingMethod: 'Per Inch'
  },

  3: {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Arnold`s Family Fun Center',
    seqNo: 1,
    address1: '100 Station Avenue',
    address2: '',
    address3: '',
    city: 'Phoenixville',
    state: 'PA',
    zipCode: '19460',
    phone: '6106660610',
    emailAddress: 'help@arnoldsffc.com',
    websiteUrl: 'http://www.arnoldsffc.com',
    billingMethod: 'Time & Materials'
  },

  4: {
    id: 4,
    name: 'ACME Markets',
    seqNo: 1,
    address1: '785 Starr Street',
    address2: '',
    address3: '',
    city: 'Phoenixville',
    state: 'PA',
    zipCode: '19460',
    phone: '6109336299',
    emailAddress: 'customerservice@local.acmemarkets.com',
    websiteUrl: 'http://www.local.acmemarkets.com',
    billingMethod: 'Fixed'
  },

  5: {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Target Grocery',
    seqNo: 1,
    address1: '200 Mill Road',
    address2: '',
    address3: '',
    city: 'Phoenixville',
    state: 'PA',
    zipCode: '19460',
    phone: '6106508700',
    emailAddress: 'info@target.com',
    websiteUrl: 'http://www.target.com',
    billingMethod: 'Per Inch'
  },

  6: {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Wegmans',
    seqNo: 1,
    address1: '600 Commerce Drive',
    address2: '',
    address3: '',
    city: 'Collegeville',
    state: 'PA',
    zipCode: '19426',
    phone: '4849021500',
    emailAddress: 'collegeville@wegmans.com',
    websiteUrl: 'http://www.wegmans.com',
    billingMethod: 'Time & Materials'
  },

  7: {
    id: 7,
    name: 'Club At Shannondell',
    seqNo: 1,
    address1: '2750 Egypt Road',
    address2: '',
    address3: '',
    city: 'Audubon',
    state: 'PA',
    zipCode: '19403',
    phone: '6103829300',
    emailAddress: 'info@theclubatshannondell.com',
    websiteUrl: 'http://www.theclubatshannondell.com',
    billingMethod: 'Fixed'
  },

  8: {
    id: 8,
    name: 'GIANT',
    seqNo: 1,
    address1: '700 Nutt Road',
    address2: 'Floor 1',
    address3: 'Phoenixville Plaza',
    city: 'Phoenixville',
    state: 'PA',
    zipCode: '19460',
    phone: '6109179086',
    emailAddress: 'customers@stores.giantfoodstores.com',
    websiteUrl: 'http://www.stores.giantfoodstores.com',
    billingMethod: 'Per Inch'
  },

  9: {
    id: 9,
    name: 'RiverCrest Golf Club & Preserve',
    seqNo: 1,
    address1: '100 Rivercrest Drive',
    address2: '',
    address3: '',
    city: 'Phoenixville',
    state: 'PA',
    zipCode: '19460',
    phone: '6109334700',
    emailAddress: 'info@rivercrestgolfclub.com',
    websiteUrl: 'http://www.rivercrestgolfclub.com',
    billingMethod: 'Time & Materials'
  },

  10: {
    id: 10,
    name: 'Phoenixville YMCA',
    seqNo: 1,
    address1: '400 East Pothouse Road',
    address2: '',
    address3: '',
    city: 'Phoenixville',
    state: 'PA',
    zipCode: '19460',
    phone: '6109335861',
    emailAddress: 'guests@philaymca.org',
    websiteUrl: 'http://www.philaymca.org',
    billingMethod: 'Fixed'
  }
};

export const JOBSITES = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Parking Lot',
    seqNo: 1,
    description: 'Main parking lot',
    imageUrl: 'https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipOH6QOgTuOFv5NzG-E7NoW0sZITls8WSkYiKRmR=w426-h240-k-no',
    address1: '200-B Mill Road',
    address2: '',
    address3: '',
    city: 'Oaks',
    state: 'PA',
    zipCode: '19456',
    geofence: {
      center: { lat: 40.12987, lng: -75.45525 },
      radius: 300
    },
    customerId: 1
  },

  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Parking Lot',
    seqNo: 1,
    description: 'Parking lot',
    imageUrl: 'https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipPgPqzprFs2exJ8O0gz5hhaoJBg7BBqtQ3TEj2U=w408-h270-k-no',
    address1: '1145 Valley Forge Road',
    address2: '',
    address3: '',
    city: 'Phoenixville',
    state: 'PA',
    zipCode: '19460',
    geofence: {
      center: { lat: 40.12040, lng: -75.48941 },
      radius: 300
    },
    customerId: 2
  },

  3: {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Parking Lot',
    seqNo: 1,
    description: 'Parking lot',
    imageUrl: 'https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipNdvemrYDKa9eBzSsnZYjcuWQLgwhAIu-mLsVeL=w408-h272-k-no',
    address1: '100 Station Avenue',
    address2: '',
    address3: '',
    city: 'Phoenixville',
    state: 'PA',
    zipCode: '19460',
    geofence: {
      center: { lat: 40.12545, lng: -75.45705 },
      radius: 300
    },
    customerId: 3
  },

  4: {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Parking Lot',
    seqNo: 1,
    description: 'Parking lot',
    imageUrl: 'https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipMLD8lpxDUdIrQNB-0RhZ7qU9QvhWVl7A2rMgMS=w426-h240-k-no',
    address1: '785 Starr Street',
    address2: '',
    address3: '',
    city: 'Phoenixville',
    state: 'PA',
    zipCode: '19460',
    geofence: {
      center: { lat: 40.12539, lng: -75.50752 },
      radius: 300
    },
    customerId: 4
  },

  5: {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Parking Lot',
    seqNo: 1,
    description: 'Parking lot',
    imageUrl: 'https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipOIgTvlgRGp_yl8C7vh50rL1ycERZWK9ZV1BQNT=w426-h240-k-no',
    address1: '200 Mill Road',
    address2: '',
    address3: '',
    city: 'Phoenixville',
    state: 'PA',
    zipCode: '19460',
    geofence: {
      center: { lat: 40.13195, lng: -75.45268 },
      radius: 300
    },
    customerId: 5
  },

  6: {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Parking Lot',
    seqNo: 1,
    description: 'Parking lot',
    imageUrl: 'https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipNeEZPv3WuRkq2sVw8wTanAmG9vUFecOHZyCHP8=w408-h306-k-no',
    address1: '600 Commerce Drive',
    address2: '',
    address3: '',
    city: 'Collegeville',
    state: 'PA',
    zipCode: '19426',
    geofence: {
      center: { lat: 40.16587, lng: -75.48392 },
      radius: 300
    },
    customerId: 6
  },

  7: {
    id: 7,
    name: 'Parking Lot',
    seqNo: 1,
    description: 'Parking lot',
    imageUrl: 'https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipPKg9C8ATZPa7iPvI-vxZuKi1MpAmHtxQqYpx_E=w408-h306-k-no',
    address1: '2750 Egypt Road',
    address2: '',
    address3: '',
    city: 'Audubon',
    state: 'PA',
    zipCode: '19403',
    geofence: {
      center: { lat: 40.12841, lng: -75.42512 },
      radius: 300
    },
    customerId: 7
  },

  8: {
    id: 8,
    name: 'Parking Lot',
    seqNo: 1,
    description: 'Parking lot',
    imageUrl: 'https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipNku09_mA9ZPNPzJ_gKNW4XUV5mgdctSmx9Ldi2=w408-h544-k-no',
    address1: '700 Nutt Road',
    address2: 'Floor 1',
    address3: 'Phoenixville Plaza',
    city: 'Phoenixville',
    state: 'PA',
    zipCode: '19460',
    geofence: {
      center: { lat: 40.13589, lng: -75.53361 },
      radius: 300
    },
    customerId: 8
  },

  9: {
    id: 9,
    name: 'Clubhouse Parking Lot',
    seqNo: 1,
    description: 'Clubhose parking lot',
    imageUrl: 'https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipNeL60iPBV1vRSr7foo9JNAiJmzUNHEYQDdgBZH=w408-h271-k-no',
    address1: '100 Rivercrest Drive',
    address2: '',
    address3: '',
    city: 'Phoenixville',
    state: 'PA',
    zipCode: '19460',
    geofence: {
      center: { lat: 40.15469, lng: -75.49364 },
      radius: 150
    },
    customerId: 9
  },

  10: {
    id: 10,
    name: 'Pro Shop Parking Lot',
    seqNo: 1,
    description: 'Pro shop parking lot',
    imageUrl: 'https://golf-pass.brightspotcdn.com/dims4/default/6cba60b/2147483647/strip/true/crop/485x313+30+0/resize/930x600!/quality/90/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgolf-pass-brightspot.s3.amazonaws.com%2F1c%2F25%2F6306f7844b6f41731ea359b29450%2F18330.jpg',
    address1: '100 Rivercrest Drive',
    address2: '',
    address3: '',
    city: 'Phoenixville',
    state: 'PA',
    zipCode: '19460',
    geofence: {
      center: { lat: 40.15446, lng: -75.49474 },
      radius: 150
    },
    customerId: 9
  },

  11: {
    id: 11,
    name: 'Parking Lot',
    seqNo: 1,
    description: 'Parking lot',
    imageUrl: 'https://www.philaymca.org/sites/default/files/styles/prgf_gallery/public/2020-11/3_0.jpg.webp?itok=3GZ-kpWX',
    address1: '400 East Pothouse Road',
    address2: '',
    address3: '',
    city: 'Phoenixville',
    state: 'PA',
    zipCode: '19460',
    geofence: {
      center: { lat: 40.11246, lng: -75.51894 },
      radius: 150
    },
    customerId: 10
  },
};

export const USERS = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    email: 'test@jobdonewell.com',
    password: 'test',
    pictureUrl: 'https://angular-academy.s3.amazonaws.com/main-logo/main-page-logo-small-hat.png'
  }
};

export function findCustomerById(customerId: number) {
  return CUSTOMERS[customerId];
}

export function findJobSitesForCustomer(customerId: number) {
  return Object.values(JOBSITES).filter(jobSite => jobSite.customerId == customerId);
}

export function authenticate(email: string, password: string) {

  const user: any = Object.values(USERS).find(user => user.email === email);

  if (user && user.password == password) {
    return user;
  } else {
    return undefined;
  }

}
```

Comment: what is the type of the return value of `await this.db.collection('customers').get()` ?

Comment: could you please create a minimum reproducible problem on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular-ivy) ?

Comment: @MaibornWolff GmbH Tobias, the return value is of type firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot<unknown>

Comment: Fabio, I've tried to do that here but Stackblitz is switching the customer variable to type any rather than unknown: [link]https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fqxj6s?file=about%2Fabout.component.ts